# MongoDB init throw in bootstrap java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/internal/SimpleMongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, wildfly, morphia

I migrate a MongoDB driver to Mongo 5 version. In my project we used before this library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace by these library :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.morphia.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

We have Java 8 version so we can't use the version 2.0 of Morphia because it's work from Java 11.
We use builder for Mongo client options and in the creation of these options a NoClassDefFoundError on SimpleMongoClient.

MongoSupport :

```
public void init() {
        logger.info("MongoDaoSupport :: Start init mongodb connection");
        Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .connectionsPerHost(Integer.parseInt(connectionsPerHost));

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(readSecondary)) {
            builder.readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());
        }

        List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<>();
        if (uri.contains(",")) {
            for (String s : uri.split(",")) {
                seeds.add(new ServerAddress(s));
            }
        } else {
            seeds.add(new ServerAddress(uri));
        }

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(seeds, MongoCredential.createCredential(username, connectDB, password.toCharArray()), builder.build());

        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
        morphia.getMapper().getOptions().setMapSubPackages(true);
        morphia.mapPackage(entitiesPackage);

        datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, dbName);
        logger.info("Mongodb connected.");
    }
```

Log :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/internal/SimpleMongoClient
    at omb.core.mongo.MongoDaoSupport.init(MongoDaoSupport.java:115)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.client.internal.SimpleMongoClient from [Module "deployment.my.ear.my-war.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Going by the dependencies of `dev.morphia.morphia:core:1.6.1` and `dev.morphia.morphia:morphia-parent:1.6.1`, you need to use the 4.1.1 version of the MongoDB driver.

Comment: that's what I was thinking but this version is not compatible with MongoDB 5...https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/compatibility/

Comment: The problem is that Morphia seems to use a class that is not on your classpath. Maybe you need to add additional dependencies, or maybe it was removed (I am not going to dig into the release notes of the MongoDB driver to find out). As it stands, Morphia 1.6.1 is built against MongoDB driver 4.1.1, so there is no expectation that it will work on a higher version (and it doesn't). So - unless there is some dependency that fixes this - you either will need to stop using Morphia, or you need to upgrade to Java 11 so you can use a newer driver version.

Comment: Do you know good alternative to Morphia ? I can'i use Spring Data because it's J2EE application who run on Wildfly 25

Answer (score 0):

Morphia 2.2.x runs perfectly fine against MongoDB 5.0.  You can find details at https://morphia.dev.

Comment: Yes I know but it's not work with Java 8 and my IT don't want to migrate at java 11.

Comment: well, you'll have to choose one or the other.  Java 8 and Morphia 1.6 are both pretty ancient tech at this point.